# Is there currently any way to mirror an official maven repo using Artifact Registry?

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I'm evaluating using Google Artifact Registry as a replacement for Nexus, and one thing that I have been unable to find in the documentation is if it is possible to mirror or proxy an official repository, for instance mavenCentral (like suggested on this site https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-1-maven-artifacts)

Has anyone else achieved this using Artifact Registry?

Comment: Even if the answer is 'no' or 'no, but it's on the roadmap'  can we please get an authoritative answer here?

Comment: @DavidRawson TL;DR 'no, but it's on the roadmap' .
Details in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently possible to proxy/mirror upstream repositories with Artifact Registry.  Support for upstream repositories is on the roadmap, with support for repos such as DockerHub, Maven, NPMJS and PyPi on the list.  It will be a proxy / pull-through cache model.

Comment: Do we have any update on when could we expect this?

Answer (score 1):

The question has been [partly answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66389438/598141) by @christiaan wrt: [mirror or proxy mavenCentral](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/11/faster-builds-for-Java-developers-with-Maven-Central-mirror.html) (though that is the default fallback if there is no other maven repository is defined anyway).

The closest Google feature request is: [maven repos proxying and/or caching public repos](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195449905). Suggest all interested upvote the feature.

Of course, what I want to do is proxy my *private* repo, but need the public feature first to even have a shot at that.

Answer (score 0):

I was also just looking into this and found there's already a mirror of Maven Central on GCP:
https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/11/faster-builds-for-Java-developers-with-Maven-Central-mirror.html